# Get year and month(as int) from datetime

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, date-format

i've created a view and need to convert a datetime to following format:

```
2011 06   (year, empty-space, two digit numeric month)
```

What's the best way to format it?

Here is the datetime(in a subquery in the view, "rounded" to month):

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,Claim_Submitted_Date), 0) AS Year_Month_Submit
```

This gives me year,month **and** day(of course `01` because datetime was rounded to first day of month):

```
CONVERT(varchar,Year_Month_Submit,112)as Year_Month_Submit
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select stuff(convert(varchar(6), Claim_Submitted_Date, 112), 5,0,' ')
```

Answer to Tim Schmelter :

You can compare the methods like this:

```
declare @i int = 0
declare @dummy varchar(20)
while @i < 1000000
begin
--set @dummy = stuff(convert(varchar(6), getdate() + @i / 1000, 112), 5,0,' ') 
set @dummy = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), getdate() + @i / 1000, 121), '-', ' ') 
set @i = @i + 1
end
```

On my server, my version takes 1 second and the other version takes 3 seconds

Comment: Works as well. I'm not sure whether yours or p.campbell's approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(YEAR(Claim_Submitted_Date))) + ' ' +
       RIGHT('0'+ LTRIM(STR(MONTH(Claim_Submitted_Date))), 2)
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Works well, but i've accepted t-clausen's approach because it is less verbose. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
STUFF(STUFF('YYYY 0M', 1, 4, YEAR(Claim_Submitted_Date)), 8 - LEN(MONTH(Claim_Submitted_Date)), 2, MONTH(Claim_Submitted_Date))
```

Or

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), @Claim_Submitted_Date, 121), '-', ' ')
```

Comment: Both work, for the first i would prefer t-clausen's approach.